# Dynamic ScrollBar into a Dynamic gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, dynamic, scrollbar

im beginner to c# windows forms
i have  a dynamic gridview which contains some rows, i want to create a dynamic scroll bar , i want it to be created when the rows are more than the form size so the user can scroll down, and i dont want it when theres only few rows..

how's that? i'v reached this code but when i scroll down nothing changing, the gridview isn't scrolling down with it, guess something is missing..

```
VScrollBar vScroller = new VScrollBar();
vScroller.Height = 200;
vScroller.Width = 30;
vScroller.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
vScroller.Minimum = 0;
vScroller.Maximum = 100;
vScroller.Value = 40;
```

---

heres my full form1.cs code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DCS
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{

        InitializeComponent();

    }
    Button b1 = new Button();
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    Button b2 = new Button();
    Form3 f3 = new Form3();
    VScrollBar vScroller1 = new VScrollBar();


    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code


        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            DataGridView dg = new DataGridView();

        }
        #endregion

        public Form2()
        {


            this.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 20, 20);
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        }
    }

    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code


        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            DataGridView dg = new DataGridView();

        }
        #endregion

        public Form3()
        {


            this.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 20, 20);
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.Text == "KM Driven")
        {
            groupBox3.Show();



        }


        else if (comboBox1.Text == "Drivers Total Driving Time")
        {
            groupBox2.Show();

        }
    }



    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (f2.Visible == false)
        {


            vScroller1.Anchor =  ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right))));
            vScroller1.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
            vScroller1.Minimum = 0;
            vScroller1.Maximum = 100;
            vScroller1.Value = 40;

            f2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(102, 395);
            f2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(401, 348);
            f2.Name = "Form2";
            f2.Text = "KM Driven";
            f2.Show();
            f2.MdiParent = this;
            f2.ControlBox = false;
            f2.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
            f2.MaximizeBox = false;
            f2.ShowIcon = false;
            f2.ResumeLayout(false);
            f2.Controls.Add(vScroller1);
            f2.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);


            f2.Refresh();


            this.dataGridView1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(401, 348);
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource;
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource.DataSource = this.dataSet1.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252;
            this.dataGridView1.Show();





            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();


            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", dateTimePicker1.Value);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", dateTimePicker2.Value);
            this.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252TableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252, dateTimePicker1.Value, dateTimePicker2.Value);

            this.dataGridView1.Refresh();



            b1.Parent = groupBox3;
            b1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(698, 59);
            b1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(98, 33);
            b1.Name = "New Button";
            b1.Text = "Close Table";
            b1.Show();
            button4.Enabled = false;

            this.dataSet1 = new DCS.DataSet1();



        }



    }

    DataGridView datagridview1 = new DataGridView();
    private void vScroller1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        datagridview1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = e.NewValue;
    }



    private void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (f2.Visible == true)
        {
            f2.Hide();
            b1.Hide();
            button4.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox3.Hide();
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox2.Hide();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (f3.Visible == false)
        {

            f3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(102, 395);
            f3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(401, 348);
            f3.Name = "From3";
            f3.Text = "Drivers Total Driving Time";
            f3.Show();
            f3.MdiParent = this;
            f3.ControlBox = false;
            f3.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
            f3.MaximizeBox = false;
            f3.ShowIcon = false;
            f3.ResumeLayout(false);
            f3.Controls.Add(dataGridView2);


            this.dataGridView2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.dataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
            this.dataGridView2.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            this.dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            this.dataGridView2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(401, 348);
            this.dataGridView2.Columns.Clear();
            this.dataGridView2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.dataGridView2.DataSource = this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource2;
            this.dataGridView2.Name = "dataGridView2";
            this.dataGridView2.ReadOnly = true;
            this.dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView2.TabIndex = 0;
            this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource2.DataSource = this.dataSet2.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252;
            this.dataGridView2.Show();

            b2.Parent = groupBox2;
            b2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(698, 57);
            b2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(98, 33);
            b2.Name = "New Button1";
            b2.Text = "Close Table";
            b2.Show();
            button5.Enabled = false;

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();

            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate2", dateTimePicker3.Value);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate2", dateTimePicker4.Value);
            this.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252TableAdapter2.Fill(this.dataSet2.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252, dateTimePicker3.Value, dateTimePicker4.Value);

            this.dataGridView2.Refresh();




        }
    }
        private void b2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (f3.Visible == true)
            {
                f3.Hide();
                b2.Hide();
                button5.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

partial class Form2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }

    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
        this.dataSet1 = new DCS.DataSet1();
        this.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252TableAdapter = new DCS.DataSet1TableAdapters.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252TableAdapter();
        this.vehiclePlateNumberDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.vehicleDescriptionDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.distanceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataSet1)).BeginInit();
        VScrollBar vScroller1 = new VScrollBar();
        vScroller1.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(vScroller_Scroll);
        vScroller1.Scroll += new System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventHandler(vScroller_Scroll);
        this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(vScroller1);



        // 
        //
        //
        //
        //


        // 
        // vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource
        // 
        this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource.DataMember = "vlm_Application_Data_Events_252";
        this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource.DataSource = this.dataSet1;
        // 
        //
        //gridview

        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.vehiclePlateNumberDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.vehicleDescriptionDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.distanceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn});
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(401, 348);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource.DataSource = this.dataSet1.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252;
        // dataSet1
        // 
        this.dataSet1.DataSetName = "DataSet1";
        this.dataSet1.SchemaSerializationMode = System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema;
        // 
        // vlm_Application_Data_Events_252TableAdapter
        // 
        this.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252TableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
        // 
        // vehiclePlateNumberDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.vehiclePlateNumberDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "VehiclePlateNumber";
        this.vehiclePlateNumberDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "VehiclePlateNumber";
        this.vehiclePlateNumberDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "vehiclePlateNumberDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        this.vehiclePlateNumberDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // vehicleDescriptionDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.vehicleDescriptionDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "VehicleDescription";
        this.vehicleDescriptionDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "VehicleDescription";
        this.vehicleDescriptionDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "vehicleDescriptionDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        this.vehicleDescriptionDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // distanceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.distanceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Distance";
        this.distanceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Distance";
        this.distanceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "distanceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        this.distanceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // Form2
        // 
        this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataSet1)).EndInit();
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form2_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataSet1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();



    }

    #endregion
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn vehiclePlateNumberDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn vehicleDescriptionDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn distanceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    private DataSet1 dataSet1;
    private DataSet1TableAdapters.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252TableAdapter vlm_Application_Data_Events_252TableAdapter;
    private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource;
    private System.Windows.Forms.VScrollBar vScrollBar1;


    public EventHandler Form2_Load { get; set; }

    public ScrollEventHandler vScroller_Scroll { get; set; }
}
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }
 }

partial class Form3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }

    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.dataGridView2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource2 = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
        this.dataSet2 = new DCS.DataSet2();
        this.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252TableAdapter = new DCS.DataSet2TableAdapters.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252TableAdapter();
        this.EventDurationDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.DriverNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource2)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataSet2)).BeginInit();


        // 
        // button1
        //
        //
        //


        // 
        // vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource2
        // 
        this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource2.DataMember = "vlm_Application_Data_Events_252";
        this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource2.DataSource = this.dataSet2;
        // 

        //gridview2


        this.dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.dataGridView2.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.EventDurationDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.DriverNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn});
        this.dataGridView2.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this.dataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        this.dataGridView2.DataSource = this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource2;
        this.dataGridView2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.dataGridView2.Name = "dataGridView2";
        this.dataGridView2.ReadOnly = true;
        this.dataGridView2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(401, 348);
        this.dataGridView2.TabIndex = 0;
        this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource2.DataSource = this.dataSet2.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252;
        // dataSet2
        // 
        this.dataSet2.DataSetName = "DataSet2";
        this.dataSet2.SchemaSerializationMode = System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema;
        // 
        // vlm_Application_Data_Events_252TableAdapter
        // 
        this.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252TableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
        // 
        // 
        // EventDurationDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.EventDurationDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "EventDuration";
        this.EventDurationDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "EventDuration";
        this.EventDurationDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "EventDurationDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        this.EventDurationDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // DriverNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.DriverNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "drivername";
        this.DriverNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "DriverName";
        this.DriverNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "DriverNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        this.DriverNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // Form3
        // 
        this.Controls.Add(dataGridView2);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource2)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataSet2)).EndInit();


    }

    #endregion
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn DriverNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn EventDurationDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
    private DataSet2 dataSet2;
    private DataSet2TableAdapters.vlm_Application_Data_Events_252TableAdapter vlm_Application_Data_Events_252TableAdapter;
    private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource vlmApplicationDataEvents252BindingSource2;


}
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the VScrollBar control to the DataGridView control collection and hook up the scroll event.

```
vScroller.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(vScroller_Scroll);
this.dataGridView.Controls.Add(vScroller);
```

This article looks has more details about those events you need to create: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20979/Paging-in-DataGridView-using-VScrollbar

EDIT:
The event listener could look like this:

```
private void vScroller_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = e.NewValue;
}
```

It's definitely not the best solution, but VerticalScrollingOffset is readonly and I failed horribly trying to bypass it through reflection.

Also keep in mind that your Minimum will be 0 and Maximum the number of rows in the datagridview (or less).

EDIT2: This is the code is tested on.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private DataGridView x = new DataGridView();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Controls.Add(x);
            x.Columns.Add("name", "header");
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                x.Rows.Add(i.ToString());
            }
            VScrollBar sc = new VScrollBar();
            sc.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
            sc.Minimum = 0;
            sc.Maximum = x.Rows.Count;
            sc.Scroll += sc_Scroll;
            x.Controls.Add(sc);
        }

        private void sc_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            x.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = e.NewValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i didnt understand what is the article trying to describe ,, and yeah i got the Scrollbar added but the gridview isn't scrolling with it .. :/

Comment: Just adding the scrollbar to the datagridview won't solve the problem because you need to hook up scroll events. Without hooked events, there's nothing that scrollbar could scroll with. It's not that simple.

Comment: alright, could you write to me the exact code i have to write ? im confused :S

Comment: its giving me an error

'System.Windows.Forms.VScrollBar' does not contain a definition for 'FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex' and no extension method 'FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.VScrollBar' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ups, it should be the datagridview instead of vScroller! My bad.

Comment: yeah the error is gone,but its still the same, the gridview isn't scrolling with it :/

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, my sample application works ok. Try some debugging or update the code here so I can see what's wrong.

Comment: edited, u can see my full form1.cs code there, i dont think form1.desigen.cs is needed too

Comment: Sorry, but there's like 4 different forms with same components and similar names. I don't have a clue which part of the code is important to you.

Comment: yeah, its form 1 which is the main form and form2 and 3 which is child forms into the mdi container, the form2 is the my object

Comment: Try putting `private void vScroller_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = e.NewValue;
}` instead of the property with the same name in Form2. Also, your code segmentation is really terrifying. I'm not surprised you can't figure out the mistake.

Comment: same, not working, i dont know why its not working with me :|